# What does the "gift" and "101010" in this rebus puzzle mean?

Tags: rebus

[image: REBUS-SIX]

What does the image in this rebus puzzle mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> present tense. The gift is a present and 101010 is 3 tens(e).

Comment: Congratz on solving this puzzle! BTW, welcome to Puzzling.SE

Answer (score 13):

I believe that it means

> The gift of life

The red box on the left is

> a gift box

And the binary number is

> 42. Famous literature and at least some popular culture considers 42 to be the "meaning of life".

Comment: +1 for teaching me the meaning of 42. But this isn't the answer I have in mind.

Comment: 42 is the answer to the question of life, the universe, and everything... but the question is not "what is the meaning of life?".

Comment: @IanMacDonald 42 is considered by some to signify life and its meaning, and the box is a gift box, hence gift of life. The answer to "what is the meaning of life" is but a logical step in reaching the final answer. Also, this is quite an old post now.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not one of the other answers, then it is probably

> Gift for 2

Comment: Nice answer. But it isn't the answer I have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it might be meaning (it doesn't really sound that great):

> The gift of knowledge and luck

The red box represents:

> A gift and luck. In many Asian countries, they wear red on Chinese New Year because it brings luck

101010 stands for:

> 42. 101010 is binary for 42. In this [site](http://tywkiwdbi.blogspot.com/2010/10/101010-is-42-in-binary.html), says that: And 42 is, of course, the "Ultimate Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything." Only with knowledge, we can answer all questions including the unknown questions of life and death.

I hope this solves your riddle (or is a good alternate answer)!

Comment: Good answer. But @MoldovanHipster got the answer I have in mind.